# configure the reporting services and/or IIS to give access permission

Tags: sql-server, iis, ssrs

how to configure the
reporting services and/or IIS to give access permission: Reporting Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find all the information you need in the product supporting documentation:

[Security and Protection (Reporting Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522728.aspx)